# NX Console plugin only showing NX Cloud UI

Tags: visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

I have installed the nx console after creating a new workspace using `nx create-nx-workspace@latest` and selecting the angular options. When I click into nx console extension, there is no option for generate etc, essentially what you see when you click the extension. it's speaking about nx cloud but i just want to generate a new component using the UI but i cant get passed the screen below

[image: See image]